# Write a loop array method to filter specific value

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

Supposing I have these two objects :

```
struct Product {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let price: Int
    let categoryId: Int
}

struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Then I create two arrays containing those objects :

```
let products = [Product(id: 1, title: "snake", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
                    Product(id: 2, title: "soap", price: 20, categoryId: 2),
                    Product(id: 3, title: "cream", price: 20, categoryId: 3),
                    Product(id: 4, title: "dog", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
                    Product(id: 5, title: "car", price: 20, categoryId: 4),
]

let categorieItems = [Category(id: 1, name: "animal"),
                Category(id: 2, name: "chemichal"),
                Category(id: 3, name: "food"),
                Category(id: 4, name: "travel"),
]
```

I want to create a new array which contains the names of all the product categories :

```
func handleCategories() -> [String] {
    var categoryNames = [String]()

    for product in products {
        for categorieItem in categorieItems {
            if product.categoryId == categorieItem.id {
                categoryNames.append(category.name)
            }
        }
    }
    return categoryNames
}
```

This method works but I want to write one with closure (I guess map() should works)

The result should be :

```
categoryNames = ["animal", "chemichal", "food", "animal", "travel"]
```

Comment: `var names = products.compactMap { product -> String? in
            return categorieItems.first(where: { $0.id == product.categoryId})?.name
        }`

Answer (score -1):

Make a dictionary that keys the category by `id`, and map each product into a category by looking up its `categoryId` in that dict.

I used a force unwrap, assuming that products don't contain any invalid `categoryId`s.

```
struct Product {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let price: Int
    let categoryId: Int
}

struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

let products = [
    Product(id: 1, title: "snake", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
    Product(id: 2, title: "soap", price: 20, categoryId: 2),
    Product(id: 3, title: "cream", price: 20, categoryId: 3),
    Product(id: 4, title: "dog", price: 20, categoryId: 1),
    Product(id: 5, title: "car", price: 20, categoryId: 4),
]

let categorieItems = [
    Category(id: 1, name: "animal"),
    Category(id: 2, name: "chemichal"),
    Category(id: 3, name: "food"),
    Category(id: 4, name: "travel"),
]

let categoriesById = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    categorieItems.map { (key: $0.id, value: $0) }
)

let productCategoryNames = products.map { categoriesById[$0.categoryId]!.name }
print(productCategories)
```